# Get required and optional fields from changeset

Tags: elixir, ecto

I read in `Ecto.schema` that we can get the `fields` and `types` of the fields by doing this:

```
Model.__schema__(:fields)
Model__schema__(:types)
```

I have module attribute constant `@required_fields` and `@optional_fields`.

Is there any way we can get `@required_fields` and `@optional_fields` from changeset or schema functions?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by required and optional here? The field can be virtual/non virtual but I don't see any way to make fields required and optional in the schema definition.

Comment: @Dogbert Let me show you the schema. I am talking about

Comment: What is `attr`? I don't see it in Ecto's documentation.

Comment: If you just want to avoid code duplication in changesets, you can just declare them as a module attribute `@required_fields [...]`

Comment: @Dogbert  I have set `@required_fields` in the changeset. i just want to fetch them as an array or list. Is there anyway we get them through changeset functions. its possible in your opinion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add the required and optional field to your `changeset` `cast` function this is how you'd do it:

```
  # using sigils list of words
  @required_fields ~w(field1 field2 field3)
  @optional_fields ~w()

  @doc """
  Builds a changeset based on the `struct` and `params`.
  """
  def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
    struct
    |> cast(params, @required_fields, @optional_fields)
    |> cast_assoc(:message_details)
  end
```

From this [Elixir Forum](https://elixirforum.com/t/get-required-fields-from-changeset/12496/2?u=cyzanfar) post it seems like you can't directly access those required fields. One suggestion would be to create a function or macro that returns these fields:

**Update**

```
def required_fields_for model do
  model.__ schema__(:fields)
  |> Enum.filter(fn field -> field in @required_fields end)
end
```

Given a model this would return the required fields.

Comment: I already added the required_fields. my question was how can i get that required and optional fields through some function

Comment: but for this I have to hard coded the required_feilds and then filter them through the Ecto.__schema__(:fields). I want them fetch dynamically based on the given model.

Comment: Well, required_fields are by nature hard-coded into your application since those are not really subject to change by your application code. But I get your point. Let me update my answer.

Comment: module attribute constants cannot be accessed outside of the module. In the above code it will return nil. but anyways thanks for your answer. :)

Comment: You'll need to import that specific function for it to work